# Google drive - allow viewing without allow download/ print

Tags: permissions, google-drive

does anyone know if it is possible for security settings to allow a google account user to VIEW my file uploaded onto Googledrive, but don't allow PRINTING hardcopy of it or downloading it ?

Comment: If it can be viewed it can be printed in some fashion no matter what you do. If nothing else a person can get a print screen and print that.

Comment: If you have access to view the document on a Google Drive account then you have access to download the file. You will have to use another cloud storage provider if you want the functionality you describe.  No;  I won't provide any suggestions since service recommendations are specifically not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: One thing you can do to discourage printing is to use a text color and background color that are hard to differentiate when printed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to disallow downloads for files uploaded to Google Drive:

1. Open google drive and find the `View details` icon.

[image: View details icon]

2. Click the `Details` tab and scroll to the bottom.

[image: Google Drive Details tab]

3. There should be a checkbox that offers to disable downloads, click it.

That's it! If you have any questions, let me know. All images courtesy of their owners.

*You cannot disallow printing to my knowledge.*